# Extending FrameLayout, child views won't show anymore

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my code with `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/frameView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"
            />
</FrameLayout>
```

The ImageView show well.

Now I have a custom layout extends from FrameLayout, e.g. MyFrameLayout.

In MyFrameLayout, I want the height of the layout is always half of the width, so my code is:

```
public class MyFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

     // 3 constructors just call super

     @Override
     protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec,
                         int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = (int) (width * 0.5);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}
```

Then use it in xml:

```
<com.test.MyFrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/frameView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"
            />
</com.test.MyFrameLayout>
```

But now the inner ImageView disappeared.

I think I don't implement `onMeasure` or `onLayout` correctly. I guess I need to resize the children views as well. But I don't know what to do now.

---

**UPDATE**

Per **TheDimasig**'s comment, I just checked my code and update my question. Thanks

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. Check your methods `onMeasure` and `onLayout` in your `MyFrameLayout` class. 2. Try to use hierarhyviewer tool for debugging. Also, if is it possible show all code of your custom layout

Comment: @TheDimasig, I just updated my question, please review:)

Answer (score 20):

The simplest way is to change the measurespec in onMeasure, but still call super:

```
 @Override
 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec,
                     int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = (int) (width * 0.5);
    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

This way you get the dimensions you want but don't have to manually measure the children.

Comment: I can confirm it works. Without calling super.onMeasure(), child views wasn't visible!

Comment: thank you so much, i've read lot of discussion, this is the only valid answer to make childs resized with parent layout !

Answer (score 10):

You don't see any child views because you don't override the method `onMeasure` correctly. You could let the super class implement the logic(so the child views will be shown) and then reset the calculated width and height for `MyFrameLayout`:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // let the super class handle calculations
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    // set again the dimensions, this time calculated as we want
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
    // this is required because the children keep the super class calculated dimensions (which will not work with the new MyFrameLayout sizes) 
    final int count = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View v = getChildAt(i);
        // this works because you set the dimensions of the ImageView to FILL_PARENT          
        v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getMeasuredWidth(),
                MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                getMeasuredHeight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    }
}
```

If that layout you posted isn't your full layout then my code might not work.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose in your `onMeasure` method you forget to call onMeasure on all child views, including your ImageView. You must go thru all your child views  and call onMeasure on them something like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        getChildAt(i).measure(....);
    }
```

Comment: I just read the source of `FrameLayout`, the `onMeasure` and `onLayout` looks pretty complicated, is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Instead overriding all method body and setDimension() try to call super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec * 0.5, heightMeasureSpec) with your params. This solution may be require to override onLayout too in this way

Comment: I tried `widthMeasureSpec*0.5`, but the final size looks not as expected. I can't get it, could you give me an working example when you have time?

Comment: Unfortunately no. If trick with super.onMeasure call doesn't work i afraid that you'll need to implement your own onMeasure and onLayout and do not forget about childs, good luck =)